# Получение параметра URLпосле ссылки #div

Tags: url

Делаю редактирование в модальном окне. Модальное окно открывается по ссылке `site.ru/page.php#modal`. Как в такого вида *url* добавить ещё и параметр, чтобы адрес выглядел как-то так: `site.ru/page.php#modal?item=11` ?

Comment: `site.ru/page.php?item=11#modal` видимо

Comment: Спасибо!!!Очень помогли